# how to take element wise logical and in ulab micropython numpy

Tags: numpy, esp32, micropython, ulab

I'm using ulab micropython on ESP32.
I can't find logical and operation. I am new to micropython. Kindly help me how do I take logical and between two numpy arrays

```py
from ulab import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([True, False, True])
arr2 = np.array([False, True, True])

print(arr1 and arr2) # gives Incorrect answer array([0.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=float32)
print(arr1 & arr2) # gives TypeError: unsupported types for __and__: 'ndarray', 'ndarray'
np.logical_and(arr1, arr2) # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'logical_and'
```

Comment: If that same code works correctly with "real" numpy, you might want to open an issue in the [ulab repository](https://github.com/v923z/micropython-ulab/issues).

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly specify `dtype` as bool, otherwise, what you have is `arr1=np.array([1.0,0.0,1.0])` and `arr2=np.array([0.0,1.0,1.0])`

Dtype is by default float (64 or 32, depending on arch). And `True` is an alias to `1` (as in regular python if you `np.array([True,False,True], dtype=np.float64)`)

And using bitwise `&` on these would fail with regular python/numpy too.

The only notable difference between ulab's version and regular one here, is the default dtype when you don't specify one: in regular python, is automatically inferred to be an array of boolean, if you don't specify dtype.

(same goes for ints, btw. In regular python, `np.array([1,2,3])` has dtype `int`, when upython would build `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` float array, unless you clearly say `np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int16)`)

So, in μpython:

```py
from ulab import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([True, False, True], dtype=np.bool)
arr2 = np.array([False, True, True], dtype=np.bool)

print(arr1 and arr2) # returns [False,True,True], that is arr2, which has its logics: `arr1`
print(arr1 & arr2) # array([False, False, True], dtype=bool). So what you want
np.logical_and(arr1, arr2) # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'logical_and'. That doesn't change
```

So logical `&` works once you ensured that array have bool dtype.

Note that you must use `np.bool`, not `bool` (contrarily to regular numpy, which gives a deprecation warning if you use `np.bool`, and not only works with `bool`, but encourages to use `bool`)

Comment: It doesn't work. Now I'm iterating thourgh a loop to get my result.
from ulab import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([True, False, True], dtype=np.bool)
arr2 = np.array([False, True, True], dtype=np.bool)


print(arr1 & arr2)

Comment: @Hamza_712 Surely it is a different error message then. Because, on my micropython/ulab, I do get the exact same error message you get without `dtype=np.bool`, and it works exactly as intended with it. What result do you get?